# CROSS APPLY to return comma separated values along with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a query to return a report that will group log records per business unit along with a comma separated list of managers assigned to each business unit, so basically there are 4 tables.

```
[dbo].[Log]
[dbo].[BusinessUnit]
[dbo].[Manager]
[dbo].[BusinessUnitManager]
```

BusinessUnit, Manager, and BusinessUnitManager for the sake of the report are only tables to gain access to basic info, the real info I need to group is contained in the Log table, my final result set should look like this:

```
BusinessUnit.Name,
Log.Code,
Count(*) LogRecordsCount,
Emails (Comma separated list of Managers assigned to the Business Unit)
```

I've been trying to get the comma separated column using CROSS APPLY but can't get it working, my current query looks like this:

```
SELECT
L.BusinessUnit,
L.Code, 
COUNT(*) AS RecordsCount,
F.Emails
FROM [dbo].[LOG] AS L
INNER JOIN [dbo].[BusinessUnit] AS D ON L.BusinessUnit = D.ID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[BusinessUnitManager] AS DSO ON D.ID = DSO.BusinessUnit
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + O.Email
    FROM [dbo].[Manager] AS O
    WHERE O.Id = DSO.IdManager
    ORDER BY O.Email ASC
    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
) F(Emails)
GROUP BY L.BusinessUnit, L.Code, F.Emails
```

The problem with this query is returning duplicated rows, one row per each manager email assigned to the business unit and my expected result should be only one row with a column containing a comma separated list of all managers email.

Current result:

```
+--------------+------+--------------+----------------------------+
| BusinessUnit | Code | RecordsCount |           Emails           |
+--------------+------+--------------+----------------------------+
| Americas     |   00 |           21 | americasmanager1@email.com |
| Americas     |   00 |           21 | americasmanager2@email.com |
| Asia         |   10 |            5 | asiamanager1@email.com     |
| Asia         |   10 |            5 | asiamanager2@email.com     |
+--------------+------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

Expected result:

```
+--------------+------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| BusinessUnit | Code | RecordsCount |                        Emails                         |
+--------------+------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Americas     |   00 |           21 | americasmanager1@email.com,americasmanager2@email.com |
| Asia         |   10 |            5 | asiamanager1@email.com,asiamanager2@email.com         |
+--------------+------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'll appreciate your help

Comment: Some sample data might be helpful here.

Comment: I think you want to change the logic of your STUFF. Something like `SELECT ',' + O.Email FROM [dbo].[Manager] AS O JOIN [dbo].[BusinessUnitManager] AS M ON M.IdManager = O.Id WHERE M.BusinessUnit = DSO.BusinessUnit ORDER BY O.Email FOR XML PATH('')` The current logic will of course produce separate lines for each manager, but this should join based on business units... Side note, I don't see an advantage to cross apply here over a regular subquery and you wouldn't have to include it in a `GROUP BY` if it were just a regular subquery...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've edited to show some sample data

Comment: @ZLK Thanks, I added the INNER JOIN inside the STUFF query and now is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

You are close, just do this in two steps:

1) store your stuff into a temp table

```
SELECT
L.BusinessUnit,
L.Code, 
O.Emails
into #tmp
FROM [dbo].[LOG] AS L
INNER JOIN [dbo].[BusinessUnit] AS D ON L.BusinessUnit = D.ID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[BusinessUnitManager] AS DSO ON D.ID = DSO.BusinessUnit
JOIN [Manager] AS O ON O.Id = DSO.IdManager
GROUP BY L.BusinessUnit, L.Code, O.Emails
```

2) use outer apply on yourself to stuff emails in one column

```
select BusinessUnit,Code, F.Emails from #tmp t 
outer apply( 
     SELECT STUFF(( SELECT ',' + inner.Email 
     FROM #tmp inner 
     WHERE t.Id = inner. 
     ORDER BY O.Email ASC 
     FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
) F(Emails) 
group by BusinessUnit,Code
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    L.BusinessUnit,
    L.Code, 
    COUNT(*) AS RecordsCount,
    (
        SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + O.Email
        FROM [dbo].[Manager] AS O
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[BusinessUnitManager] AS DSO ON O.Id = DSO.IdManager 
        WHERE 
            DSO.BusinessUnit = D.ID
        ORDER BY O.Email ASC
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
    ) as Emails
FROM [dbo].[LOG] AS L
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[BusinessUnit] AS D ON L.BusinessUnit = D.ID
GROUP BY L.BusinessUnit, L.Code, D.ID
```